# PHP Built in Server with SQLite

Tags: php, windows, sqlite

I am trying to create a portable web application using PHP's built in server on Windows. I need to have a user authentication system and I figured SQLite was perfect because of it being portable and a small file size. I'm ending up with errors though. (Note: I do not want to edit the php.ini installed by default on my system since this will be given out to other people)

I have this:

```
$dbh = new PDO('sqlite:sqlite/minepanel.db');
```

which returns this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'
```

With some research, I figured I needed to do something along the lines of having a custom php.ini for my application. I created a php.ini in the directory the built in server runs out of with this content:

```
sqlite3.extension_dir = "ext"
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite.dll
```

With my startup script looking like this:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -c php.ini
```

I'm confused now as to how to get PHP to talk to SQLite when running PHP's built in server without modifiying the PHP install php.ini